# Read data effectively in AWS EMR Spark cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am trying to get acquainted with Amazon Big Data tools and I want to preprocess data from S3 for eventually using it for Machine Learning.

I am struggling to understand how to effectively read data into an AWS EMR Spark cluster.

I have a Scala script which takes a lot of time to run, most of that time is taken up by Spark's explode+pivot on my data and then using Spark-CSV to write to file.

But even reading the raw data files takes up too much time in my view.

Then I created a script only to read in data with `sqlContext.read.json()` from 4 different folders (data sizes of 0.18MB, 0.14MB, 0.0003MB and 399.9MB respectively). I used `System.currentTimeMillis()` before and after each read function to see how much time it takes and with 4 different instances' settings the results were the following:

```
           m1.medium (1) | m1.medium (4) | c4.xlarge (1) | c4.xlarge (4)
1. folder   00:00:34.042 |  00:00:29.136 |  00:00:07.483 |  00:00:06.957
2. folder   00:00:04.980 |  00:00:04.935 |  00:00:01.928 |  00:00:01.542
3. folder   00:00:00.909 |  00:00:00.673 |  00:00:00.455 |  00:00:00.409
4. folder   00:04:13.003 |  00:04:02.575 |  00:03:05.675 |  00:02:46.169
```

The number after the instance type indicates how many nodes were used. 1 is only master and 4 is one master, 3 slaves of the same type.

Firstly, it is weird that reading in first two similarly sized folders take up different amount of time.

But still how does it take so much time (in seconds) to read in less than 1MB of data?
I had 1800MB of data a few days ago and my job with data processing script on c4.xlarge (4 nodes) took 1,5h before it failed with error:

controller log:

```
INFO waitProcessCompletion ended with exit code 137 : hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-...
INFO total process run time: 4870 seconds
2016-07-01T11:50:38.920Z INFO Step created jobs: 
2016-07-01T11:50:38.920Z WARN Step failed with exitCode 137 and took 4870 seconds
```

stderr log:

```
16/07/01 11:50:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 24 missing tasks from ShuffleMapStage 4 (MapPartitionsRDD[21] at json at DataPreProcessor.scala:435)
16/07/01 11:50:35 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 4.0 with 24 tasks
16/07/01 11:50:36 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 4 contains a task of very large size (64722 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
16/07/01 11:50:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5330, localhost, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 66276000 bytes)
16/07/01 11:50:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5331, localhost, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 66441997 bytes)
16/07/01 11:50:36 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5330)
16/07/01 11:50:36 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5331)
Command exiting with ret '137'
```

This data was doubled in size over the weekend. So if I get ~1GB of new data each day now (and it will grow soon and fast) then I hit big data sizes very soon and I really need an effective way to read and process the data quickly.

How can I do that? Is there anything that I am missing? I can upgrade my instances, but for me it does not seem normal that reading in 0.2MB of data with 4x c4.xlarge (4 vCPU, 16ECU, 7.5GiB mem) instances take 7 seconds (even with inferring data schema automatically for ~200 JSON attributes).

Comment: How many files are in each directory? if there is a large amount of files, reading in of many separate files can sometimes be a bottleneck

Comment: In these specific folders I have 17, 17, 1 and 2409 files respectively. Total number in my S3 bucket is currently 15061 files with a total size of 3946.23 MB. So I don't think it's the amount of files that is the problem.

Comment: google the "Small files problem" with Spark

Comment: Although I still have problems with it, your answer at least pushed me in the right direction. I have found some suggestions to create larger files or ideally files with the same size as Spark's default block size. For 3GB of data, the reading time decreased from 11min30sec for multiple small files to 1min30sec for 1 large file. Now, after removing `.setMaster("local[4]").set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g")` from my SparkConf, reading 4GB from multiple files took 4:46 and 3GB from single file took 21 seconds. This is a huge improvement :)

Comment: I will do more research until I am satisified with my results and then I will try to formulate a thorough answer here myself. Thanks!